# Plolty combine timeline on one line into subplots

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

I try to put a px.timeline into subplot, but my timeline format change.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.subplots as sp

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job B", Start='2009-02-28', Finish='2009-04-15'),
dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job A", Start='2009-04-15', Finish='2009-05-30')
])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-15', Finish='2009-02-15'),
    dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job B", Start='2009-02-15', Finish='2009-04-28'),
    dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job A", Start='2009-04-28', Finish='2009-05-30')
])

fig1 = px.timeline(df1, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="unit",color="Task")
fig2 = px.timeline(df2, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="unit",color="Task")


fig_sub = sp.make_subplots(rows=2)
for i in range(0,len(fig['data'])):
    fig_sub.append_trace(fig1['data'][i], row=1, col=1)


for i in range(0,len(fig['data'])):
    fig_sub.append_trace(fig2['data'][i], row=2, col=1)

fig_sub.update_xaxes(type='date')
```

My fig 1 look like that
[image]

but one into subplit i got this
[image]

Any idea of how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Your code is not running properly, please try to fix it. It does not run on my machine.

Comment: It has been corrected, the initial code should work. thnks

Answer (score 2):

I found it, we need to add

```
fig_sub.update_layout(barmode="overlay")
```

by default in `sub_plots` it is put in `barmode="group"`